# Connection closed by [SERVER_IP]

Tags: ssh, ip, ssh-keys

I'm not a guru of ssh but somehow I cannot connect to server with IP and username:

`ssh -p [PORT] [USERNAME]@[SERVER_IP]`

Response is always:

`Connection closed by [SERVER_IP]`

The problem is on the remote server side?

I'm on Mac OS X (mavericks).

**update:** log looks as follows:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to [SERVER_IP] port 22068.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/dmitri/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/dmitri/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/dmitri/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dmitri/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dmitri/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0 
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: [SERVER_IP]:22068
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[SERVER_IP]:22068" from file "/Users/dmitri/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE:** sshd_config

```
Port 22068
Protocol 1,2 
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
```

Comment: What is the output if you at '-vvv' to the command?
ssh -vvv -p [PORT] [USERNAME]@[SERVER_IP]

Comment: @jasperado check update with log please

Comment: Which OS is running on the server? Do you have access to the server (other than the not working ssh)?

Comment: @jasperado Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @jasperado yes I have access to the server

Comment: @jasperado I've checked logs on the server it always complains about ``error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key``

Comment: that's what I thought. Try to regenerate the server's host key using the following command on the server: dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server

Comment: @jasperado that command doesnt help unfortunately

Comment: Then please post the output of: `ls -la /Users/dmitri/.ssh` on your computer and `ls -la /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key` on the server.

Comment: @jasperado ``ls -la /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key`` on server outputs ``-rw---- 1 root root 1675 Jun 23 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key``

Comment: @jasperado and on my machine much more files here - ``drwx------   5 dmitri  staff   170 May 12  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 60 dmitri  staff  2040 Jun 23 10:38 ..
-rw-------   1 dmitri  staff  1675 May 30  2013 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--   1 dmitri  staff   410 May 30  2013 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 dmitri  staff  5999 Dec 19  2013 known_hosts``

Comment: @jasperado it looks like permissions are right.. I'm really stucked with this problem :( one more input from logs is ``fatal no supported key exchange algorithms preauth``

Comment: Ok. So even though the /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key exists and has the right permissions, the server `could not load host key`. Reconfiguring open-ssh did not work. Let's see you sshd config.

Comment: @jasperado take a look on the updated question please

Comment: Is that the whole config? Did you create it? Please check if sshd is running: `service ssh status` and verify that openssh-server is installed: `dpkg -l openssh-server`

Comment: where are the logs stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try debugging this problem differently. Since you have access to the server, run the ssh server manually with the -d (for `debug`) option:

```
  sudo service ssh stop
  sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
```

This will increase the verbosity level of the server, just like the -vvv option for the client. The output of the second command will go to standard error,you may capture it, analyze, and, if in doubt, post the last lines here for further discussion.

You can also use another command,

```
 sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -T
```

to check the validity of your configuration and of your keys.

You sdirectory hould also check the permissions you have, on the client and on the server, for the .ssh for the users **from** whom and **to** whom you are connecting (use 700=, the existence of an *authorized_keys* file  in the .ssh directory of the user you are connecting to, and the permissions for the keys in the .ssh directory of the client (they should be 700).

EDIT:

> sudo service ssh stop points me to stop: Unknown instance:

This means you do not have an ssh server running on your Ubuntu machine. Have you downloaded   the package ssh? Does it start correctly? Try running it with the command I gave above,

```
  sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d
```

and check its output

Comment: ``sudo service ssh stop`` points me to ``stop: Unknown instance:``

Comment: @Kosmetika This means you do not have an ssh server running on your Ubuntu machine, pkease see the edit to my post.

Answer (score 2):

Check the permissions on the `/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key` and `/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key` files.
They must be `0600`. I had the same problem and nothing worked. But when I did a

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d
```

I got a bunch of error messages nagging about those 2 files (that their `0644` permission was “too open”). Everything was fixed by giving those 2 commands:

```
sudo chmod 600 /etc/ssh_host_rsa_key
sudo chmod 600 /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a 'problem' on the remote side. The error suggests that a connection is made, but then closed by the server. There are several things you could check:

- Check for access lists/other security controls in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
- Check TCP wrappers (`/etc/hosts.allow`, `/etc/hosts.deny`)

Comment: you can check log update where I ran command with ``-vvv`` option, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone else, my problem when I received this error was client side. I had mistyped the `[USERNAME]` portion of the command.